# How can i kill last token from Firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The Firebase authentication  token expires in one hour. When the user logs out, and then logs back in, if the token of the past session does not have an expired lifetime, it is still read as valid. Is there a way to disable the token of the last user session if it still has a lifetime?

Comment: Sure thing. Just [sign the user out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut) to forget their current tokens.

Comment: @Puf, 
I tested the cloud function to validate the token. When I use the `signOut()` method, the token is deleted, and when I log in, a new token is generated. But what I said is that when I log in again, the token from the previous session still works if it does not have time expired

Comment: There is no way to invalidate an existing ID token. By their nature they're bearer tokens that are valid until expiration. That why signing the user out deletes it.